# E2016 Array type required.using PSingle variable

Tags: delphi, pointers

First, sorry for my English, I'm Spanish.

I have a lot of time trying to translate this portion of code from delphi vcl to fmx.
this is the code:

```
procedure process(Process_samples: Longint);
var
  offs: longint;
  pBuffer: PSingle;
  sum: double;
  x: longint;
begin
  pBuffer := buffer.ptrBegin;  //-->>buffer.ptrbegin is a psingle 
  for offs := windowStart to windowLen do
  begin
    sum := 0;
    for x := 0 to process_samples - 1 do
    begin
      sum := sum + pBuffer[x] * pBuffer[x + offs];    
    end;

  end;
end;
```

I receive this error:

`[dcc error] unit1.pas: E2016 Array type required.`

I need read a single value from psingle on the position x, and I don't know how to do this.

Can someone give me help?

I'm newbie in Firemonkey and I want translate my application from delphi vcl to fmx.

Comment: The code you've posted won't differ between VCL and FMX; it may differ between Delphi versions, but there is not GUI content, so VCL and FMX are irrelevant. What specific Delphi version(s) are you using for the original and new versions, and what is the specific definition of `buffer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code relies on [Pointer Math](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Pointer_Math_%28Delphi%29), so make sure it is actually turned on in your code:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
```

See Embarcadero's documentation for more details about working with compiler conditionals and directives:

[Conditional compilation (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29)

[Delphi Compiler Directives (List) Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Delphi_Compiler_Directives_%28List%29_Index)